# Quasi-likelihood and complementary log-log link

Tags: generalized-linear-model, link-function, quasi-likelihood

I need help to understand how R computes the adjusted value when I use the quasi-likelihood distribution and complementary log-log link with variance function *mu(1-mu)*.

My data are rates from continuous numbers *(mycelial grow [cm] in treatment / mycelial grow [cm] in control)* with outcomes (0< y < 1). My coefficients are ß1=-2.2645832 (intercept) and ß2=0.07346398

I tried ***y = 1-exp(-exp(ß1+ß2x))*** but can´t find the same value.
There is a similar equation ***y = mi(1-exp(-exp(ß1+ß2x)))*** but I don´t know what is and how to calculate this ***mi***.

Sincerely, I need help (P.S. This is my first attempt here. Sorry for unsuitable formats)